# Edgewall Trac: retrospectives of notifications

Tags: trac

Hello,

is it possible at all to include not only the status and most recent comment in messages sent on ticket creation and ticket changes? I'd like to see much more, say all available retrospective information, that is the entire Change history.

Maybe someone already configured Trac this way. If so, I'd be very grateful for information about that configuration, including the Trac version used with that application.

Cheers,
Thx

Comment: Going out on a limb by your username... Do you speak Russian? If so, feel free to explain to me in Russian what you're trying to ask and I'll translate it into a more understandable version in English.

Comment: I think it is relevant for people coming here later. So I made an attempt to paraphrase your question. I'm no native speaker either, but due to apparent lack of permission this will get reviewed anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trac has change listener interfaces for binding modules to act on changes, i.e. notify on ticket change. See the [Trac wiki documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints) for descriptions of the I***ChangeListener extension points available by now.

But you'll notice, that the data provided by these interfaces provide only limited information about the changed resource, such as ID and the changed/old vs. new values. So your request can't be solved at all by configuration alone.

While it might be possible to do more complete notification by coding look-ups for additional data in the Trac db, even this isn't possible under all circumstances. Think i.e. about ticket deletion, where everything already has gone when the change listeners are fired with the pre-defined information.

Comment: Maybe it's just because I'm not a native speaker, but "...to email address the trade came full,..." doesn't make sense to me. If you got enough pointers, you should accept the answer, or ask more specifically to get more details.